# Disabling auto-open

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, mount

How do I keep CD/USB automounting (works fine) BUT without auto-opening in Nautilus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System->Preferences->Removable Drives (only in Ubuntu version 9.04 and below)

There should be setting there to chose what happens when removable media is [inserted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB).

Comment: I don't see that option in my menu... should I `dpkg-reconfigure` something?
OR do you know how to get to that screen manually (alt-f2)?

Comment: @diego I am not on my ubuntu box. the option is there. let me get you a link I have modified my answer with a link.

Comment: Excellent link, that'll probably do!

Comment: "Removable Drives and Media" was removed from System > Preferences starting with 9.10.

Answer (score 10):

From inside Nautilus: Edit > Preferences > Media

Here you can change behavior for recognized media types (CD, Music Player, Photos, etc.) and unrecognized ("Browse media when inserted" option).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That the UI way to change /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount_open, right?

Comment: @RolandTaylor: I actually fixed the problem with dustyprogrammer's link. Both solutions do the same in the end.